# Realm Swift - enumeration values 'connect_timeout' and 'bad_timestamp" not handled in switch

Tags: swift, realm

I just updated to Xcode 9.4 (Swift 4.1) and also Realm 3.6.0 via cocoapods .  For the first time, I'm getting a compiler "semantic issue" warning:

> Enumeration values 'connect_timeout' and 'bad_timestamp' not handled in switch

I have cleaned the build folder and re-built, but no luck.  The warning persists.  Any ideas?

Edit: I should have mentioned that the warning is within the Realm Framework.  Specifically, sync_session.cpp:

```
switch (static_cast<ClientError>(error_code.value())) {
        case ClientError::connection_closed:
        case ClientError::pong_timeout:
            // Not real errors, don't need to be reported to the binding.
            return;
        case ClientError::unknown_message:
        case ClientError::bad_syntax:
        case ClientError::limits_exceeded:
        case ClientError::bad_session_ident:
        case ClientError::bad_message_order:
        case ClientError::bad_progress:
        case ClientError::bad_changeset_header_syntax:
        case ClientError::bad_changeset_size:
        case ClientError::bad_origin_file_ident:
        case ClientError::bad_server_version:
        case ClientError::bad_changeset:
        case ClientError::bad_request_ident:
        case ClientError::bad_error_code:
        case ClientError::bad_compression:
        case ClientError::bad_client_version:
        case ClientError::ssl_server_cert_rejected:
        case ClientError::bad_file_ident:
        case ClientError::bad_client_file_ident:
        case ClientError::bad_client_file_ident_salt:
            // Don't do anything special for these errors.
            // Future functionality may require special-case handling for existing
            // errors, or newly introduced error codes.
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Add the code, please

Answer (score 1):

Try to add two lines before the "break":

```
case ClientError::connect_timeout:
case ClientError::bad_timestamp:
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. However, I know how to technically fix the error, but the problem is... this is not my framework to fix. Was wondering if there are other problems with this Realm version that we don’t know about?

Comment: Agree with @mguren, but it is nice to get rid of the warnings, until the next pod update. Deep in my mind I also have the idea that other problems may linger around.   That's why I try to avoid third party dependencies (i.e. Pod stuff)